# How to run shell script in php

Tags: php, bash

I want to run a shell script from `run_bash_script.php`

Code of run_bash_script.php:

```
<?php

$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('C:\xampp\htdocs\RTLS_Final\2ndRTLS');
$output = shell_exec('./bashscript.sh');
chdir($old_path);
echo "$old_path\n";
echo "<pre>$output</pre>\n"; 
?>
```

Ouput: `C:\xampp\htdocs\RTLS_Final\2ndRTLS`

code of bashscript.sh

```
STRING="Solar Eclipse"
# print the contents of the variable on screen
echo $STRING

python pythoncode.py
```

code of pythoncode.py

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def gps_solve(distances_to_station, stations_coordinates):
    def error(x, c, r):
        return sum([(np.linalg.norm(x - c[i]) - r[i]) ** 2 for i in range(len(c))])
    l = len(stations_coordinates)
    S = sum(distances_to_station)
    # compute weight vector for initial guess
    W = [((l - 1) * S) / (S - w) for w in distances_to_station]
    # get initial guess of point location
    x0 = sum([W[i] * stations_coordinates[i] for i in range(l)])
    # optimize distance from signal origin to border of spheres
    return minimize(error, x0, args=(stations_coordinates, distances_to_station), method='Nelder-Mead').x

def calculateDistance(rssi):
  txPower = -59 #hard coded power value. Usually ranges between -59 to -65
  if rssi == 0:
    return -1.0

  ratio = rssi*1.0/txPower
  if (ratio < 1.0):
    return ratio**10
  else:
    distance =  (0.89976)*ratio**7.7095 + 0.111
    return distance

# print(calculateDistance(-71))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # stations = list(np.array([[1,1], [0,1], [1,0], [0,0]]))
    stations = list(np.array([[13.39026121057006,52.51264336892332], [13.39033590842385,52.512538230285614], [13.390433408780382,52.51264251710566]]))
    distances_to_station = [calculateDistance(-71), calculateDistance(-69), calculateDistance(-45)]
    # return gps_solve(distances_to_station, stations)
    print(gps_solve(distances_to_station, stations))
```

When I run bash script from git the output is:

[image: Output of bash script on running it from git]

Comment: Put `bash` before the path: `shell_ecec('bash bashscript.sh')` . You should put in `shell_exec()` literally what you type in your shell.

Comment: I tried it but no luck application stopped working

Comment: Are there any exceptions in your logs etc.. ?

Comment: No exceptions it just gives output stated as
**C:\xampp\htdocs\RTLS_Final\2ndRTLS
<pre></pre>**

Comment: "when I run bash script from git" -- huh? You mean from a shell, right? Anyhow, you're not running the script directly there but you start a shell that interprets ("runs") the script. Do the same in PHP. Further, your question's not really good: Things like "doesn't work" are not suitable error descriptions. Please, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, you are required to reduce your example code to a [mcve]. Most of your code is irrelevant for that. Lastly, please read the description of tags that you apply after reducing your code. There's also way too much there.

Comment: @AbdulWajid : What is the point of using bash here? In your bash script, you only print out a fixed string (unnecessarily assigning it to a variable), which you could do equally well in PHP or Python, and then calling the Python program. You could invoke `python` directly from PHP.

Comment: Could you explain how to run python directly from php

Answer (score 0):

You should put in `shell_exec()` literally what you type in your shell.

That being said. Put `bash` before the script path.

```
// ... original code ....

$output = shell_exec('bash ./bashscript.sh');

// ... original code continues ....
```

Answer (score -2):

To run php script you should run like this

```
php run_bash_script.php
```

Comment: He doesn't want to know how to run a PHP script from shell, but how to run a a shell script using PHP.

Comment: @mike i tried to run the run_bash_script.php separately but it just gives output
**C:\xampp\htdocs\RTLS_Final\2ndRTLS**